# Change values of four nearest neighbours of certain matrix cells

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix in which the value -1 is randomly distributed (see the yellow cells in the image). The rest of the matrix is filled with 0s (blue cells).

I now need to fill the cells that neighbour a -1 from either left, right, top or bottom with 1. In case of several cells with -1 next to each other, these -1 should not be overwritten.

I have tried with two nested for-loops, but it gets really tricky with the indices. I would appreciate any help.

[image: see figure]

Answer (score 4):

I'm borrowing the example matrix generation from [Vahe Tshitoyan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44865091/2586922):

```
A = zeros(10,10);
A(randi(100,1,20))=-1;
colormap(parula(3));    % set colormap: blue, yellow, bluish green
image(-A*2+1);          % -A*2+1 is just a trick to get the desired colors
axis square
```

You can

1. Use 2D convolution ([`conv2`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html)) to write `1` into the cells that surround those that equal `-1`.
2. Overwrite `-1` into the original cells.

That is,

```
mask = [0 1 0; 1 0 1; 0 1 0];             % define neighbouthood mask
B = double(conv2(-A, mask, 'same') > 0);  % step 1
B(A==-1) = -1;                            % step 2
figure
colormap(parula(3));
image(-B*2+1+3*(B==1));                   % similar trick to that used before
axis square
```

Example original matrix (`A`) and result matrix (`B`):

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`circshift`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/circshift.html) function.

```
% generating the matrix
A = zeros(10,10);
A(randi(100,1,20))=-1;
figure(1);imagesc(A, [-1 1]);

% neighbours + no circular boundary condition
downshifted = circshift(A, 1, 1);downshifted(1,:)=0;
upshifted = circshift(A, -1, 1);upshifted(end,:)=0;
leftshifted = circshift(A, -1, 2);leftshifted(:,end)=0;
rightshifted = circshift(A, 1, 2);rightshifted(:,1)=0;

% combining neighbours and removing where A~=0
neighbours = (downshifted|upshifted|leftshifted|rightshifted)&~A;

% final matrix
B = A+neighbours;
figure(2);imagesc(B, [-1 1]);
```

One thing to be careful with is the circular boundary conditions of `circshift`. This is why I manually set `downshifted(1,:)=0;`, etc.. Unless, of course, you actually want circular boundary conditions. This is what I get

[image: before and after]

---

There is also this, in my opinion more efficient way of doing this.

For every given pixel, linear indices of the four nearest neighbours are given by the offsets of

```
offsets = [-n, -1, +1, +n];
```

where `n` is the number of rows. Therefore, you can compute the indices of all neighbours using something like

```
minusOneInd = find(A==-1); % the linear indices of -1s
indices = unique(bsxfun(@plus, minusOneInd, offsets)); % all neighbours
```

This, however, will lead to a bit of trouble due to the edges and indexes running out. One way to solve this is to pad your initial matrix with 0s, then remove the padding after the operations are complete. A full code that does what you require can then be written as below, assuming `A` is your initial matrix.

```
Ap = padarray(A,[1 1]); % to get rid of the edge effects
n = size(Ap, 1);
offsets = [-n, +1, -1, +n]; % index offsets of four neighbours

minusOneInd = find(Ap==-1); % finding the indices of -1s
indices = unique(bsxfun(@plus, minusOneInd, offsets)); % neighbours
% now, remove out of range indices and indices where A is -1
indices(indices<1|indices>numel(Ap)|ismember(indices, minusOneInd))=[]; 

Ap(ind2sub(size(Ap),indices)) = 1; % assigning the ones
B = Ap(2:end-1,2:end-1); % this is what we want
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer using *circshift* by @Vahe Tshitoyan seems good, while I was using *for* loop:

```
M = zeros(10);
M(randi(100, [1,20])) = -1;
siz = size(M);
[I, J] = ind2sub(siz, find(M == -1)); % row, column indice of those -1
for i = 1:numel(I)
    if I(i)>1 && M(I(i)-1, J(i))~=-1, M(I(i)-1, J(i)) = 1; end % above
    if I(i)<siz(1) && M(I(i)+1, J(i))~=-1, M(I(i)+1, J(i)) = 1; end % below
    if J(i)>1 && M(I(i), J(i)-1)~=-1, M(I(i), J(i)-1) = 1; end % left
    if J(i)<siz(2) && M(I(i), J(i)+1)~=-1, M(I(i), J(i)+1) = 1; end % right
end
```